# Visual Basic, writing to file

Tags: vb.net

Hey I am trying to write some data into a fail using a table.
I get it to work but, every time I add a new piece of data the last piece of data is overwritten causing the file to remain 2 lines long.

Every time I click Button1 I want it to send to file all the previous data captured.

```
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Michael\Documents\University\Application Programming\Assignment\Logs\AuditLog.htm", "<table border=1 width=100%>  <tr><td> Staff Name </td> <td> Computer Number </td> <td> Fault </td> <td> Assigned Technician </td> <td> Date Submitted </td> </tr> ", False)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Michael\Documents\University\Application Programming\Assignment\Logs\AuditLog.htm", "<tr> <td> <b> </b>" & StaffName & "</td> <td>" & ComputerNumber & "</td> <td>" & Fault & "</td> <td> " & AssignedTechnician & "</td> <td> " & DateSub & "</tr>", True)
```

This is where my problem is at. Im thinking I need a for loop of some kind on the second line. But not to sure how to go about it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\test.txt"
Dim i As Integer
Dim aryText(4) As String

aryText(0) = "Mary WriteLine"
aryText(1) = "Had"
aryText(2) = "Another"
aryText(3) = "Little"
aryText(4) = "One"

Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)

For i = 0 To 4
objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))
Next

objWriter.Close()
MsgBox("Text Appended to the File")
```

There more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/513f326e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets8p4.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. I run into the problem of I want to have a line that only is used once.

Which creates <table border=1 width=100%>
I need this to start the document off. 

This what I got
        'aryText(0) = "<tr><td> " & StaffName & "</td>"
        'aryText(1) = "<td> " & ComputerNumber & "</td>"
        'aryText(2) = "<td> " & Fault & "</td>"
        'aryText(3) = "<td> " & AssignedTechnician & "</td>"
        'aryText(4) = "<td> " & DateSub & "</td></tr>"

But i need the table if you get what I mean lol.